# MySQL Get the number of times values appear in a column?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have a table that holds the outcomes of rounds of a contest. This table has a result column that contains the values 'won' 'lost' or 'draw'. How can I group by the competitor and get the counts of specific values? The idea is to be able to sort competitors based on the number of wins and losses, and calculate scores within the database query.

So, my table is:

```
+--------------+---------+--------+
| CompetitorId | MatchId | Result |
+--------------+---------+--------+
| 1            | 1       | won    |
| 2            | 1       | lost   |
| 1            | 2       | won    |
| 3            | 2       | lost   |
+--------------+---------+--------+
```

The result I am trying to get is:

```
+--------------+------+--------+
| CompetitorId | Wins | Losses |
+--------------+------+--------+
| 1            | 2    | 0      |
| 2            | 0    | 1      |
| 3            | 0    | 1      |
+--------------+------+--------+
```

The query I tried was this:

```
SELECT CompetitorId, COUNT(result='won') AS wins, COUNT(result='lost') AS losses
FROM match_competitors
GROUP BY CompetitorId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sum with a case inside, giving a value of 1 when is the column you need and 0 when is not:

```
SELECT CompetitorId, sum(case result
                              when 'won' then 1
                              else 0
                         end) as wins,
                         sum(case result
                              when 'lost' then 1
                              else 0
                         end) as losses
FROM match_competitors
GROUP BY CompetitorId
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was looking at so many horrible options, joins I could sum on, etc... THANK YOU! I always forget about case statements. *patiently waits for the accept timer to tick down...*